# Is there a way to enable OAuth 2.0 for a new Google Cloud Project via the commandline?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-oauth, gcloud

The process of setting up a [setting up an oauth consent screen](https://developers.google.com/workspace/guides/configure-oauth-consent) and [getting the credentials.json](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/quickstart/python#authorize_credentials_for_a_desktop_application) is tedious to do every time I create project to use Google APIs. Is there a way to do this from the command line?

I wasn't able to figure out how to enable oauth with the gcloud cli by Googling.

Comment: This is on-going feature request, you can also monitor this [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/35907249) for more update for this issue

Answer (score 0):

You may follow the progress of this issue's feature request by paying attention to the [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/35907249).